# C#をやっていた人間がQtのプログラムを組む際の考え方

Tags: qt

普段C#をやっていて、Qt(C++)を初めてやることになりました

Qtのイベントの考え方なのですが
C#のイベントようなものはsignalとslotをconnect関数でつなぎ合わせるという考え方で置き換えていけば良いのでしょうか
C++のコールバックを更に拡張したような実装ですがその考え方で会っていますか

また、C#のようなスレッドセーフな排他キュー(ConcurrentQueue)は自分で実装するという考え方でいいのでしょうか
それとも探し方がまずいだけで、実は似たような機能やクラスがあったりするのでしょうか

Comment: スレッド系は古いですがこれらが参考になるのでは？ [スレッドの同期について学ぼう(その１）](https://qiita.com/hermit4/items/6282640a7fe4dbcdec43), [( Qt C++ )QThreadのサブクラス化によるマルチスレッドの実現](http://memotiyou.blogspot.com/2012/01/qt-c-qthread_2497.html) 等と、同じ人の関連記事

Comment: ありがとうございます。その中だと他のスレッドをがっちり阻止したいのでMutexが適していそうです。Qtはまだスレッドの立て方も良くわかっていないのでそれも含めてそちらのページを見てみようと思います